# ServerError: AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but none of the currently signed in user(s) match the requested login hint"

Tags: msal.js

SSO fails "ServerError: AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but none of the currently signed in user(s) match the requested login hint"
when I use same account for both work and personal azure account.

I have 2 AAD accounts (one is with my work account and the other one is personal account but both attached with same email and both are using same credentials).  When I use msal.js library for single sign on application. It takes me to my work account where it asks me to validate the credentials (using standard pop up dialog) by giving full email address and does not authenticate properly even if give right credentials. As I need to login using my personal account
I expect this should validate using my ad alias@company.com credentials. I tried with different account option in the dialog, but it fails and shows up same full email account.
How can I use my adalias@company.com as a default user id?

Here are the piece of the code I am trying to use.

```
var msalConfig = {
     auth: {
       clientId: 'xxxxxxxxxx', // This is your client ID
       authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}"  // This is tenant info
     },
     cache: {
       cacheLocation: "localStorage",
       storeAuthStateInCookie: true
     }
};

var graphConfig = {
  graphMeEndpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me"
};

var requestObj = {scopes: ["user.read", "email"]};  
// Is there a way to change here to get the required user id?

var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
// Register Callbacks for redirect flow     
myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallbacks(acquireTokenRedirectCallBack, 
acquireTokenErrorRedirectCallBack);
myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallback(authRedirectCallBack);

function signIn() {
  myMSALObj.loginRedirect(requestObj).then(function (loginResponse) {
    // Successful login        
    acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph();
  }).catch(function (error) {
    // Please check the console for errors
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Here is the error message I get:

> ServerError: AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but none of the 
>   currently signed in user(s) match the requested login hint

The expected result is seamless login to other application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide a login_hint to indicate the user you are trying to authenticate try:

```
var requestObj = {scopes: ["user.read", "email"], loginHint: "adalias@company.com"};
```

Reference https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/wiki/FAQs#q10-how-to-pass-custom-state-parameter-value-in-msaljs-authentication-request-for-example-when-you-want-to-pass-the-page-the-user-is-on-or-custom-info-to-your-redirect-uri